# Recruiter hasn't gotten back to me after requesting my availability for an interview

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment

A little over a week ago, I received an email from a recruiter requesting my availability for an interview. I responded within a few hours and have still not received anything to date. I even sent a follow-up email. Am I out of luck? And in the event that they did find a different candidate, is it normal for them to not email me back saying so?

Answer (score 5):

If they want you , they will chase you or they will dump you like no tomorrow. That's the norm. In short , he is not chasing you. SO there must be a reason which only he knows. DO not put your expectations on someone just because they asked for something. Nothing is sure unless you sign on the dotted line. Keep looking and forget this. You will get used to it

Comment: Pretty much this. I've had recruiters take weeks before giving a single reply. However after they ask for availability I've always had replies within 1 or 2 days to a max of 1 week. The ones that didn't reply within that time either never replied again or said the position was filled.

Comment: Have to disagree slightly. Recruiters are humans too. No harm in giving them a call and seeing what's up. It'll keep you in their minds which is only good, even if this opportunity is gone it might make them more likely to think of you for the next one.

Comment: @colmde I was thinking about giving her a call today. What would a standard followup phonecall look like without sounding too pushy?